# Kinect Record Only When One Body/Skeleton Is in the Frame

Tags: visual-studio, kinect, kinect-sdk

I need to write a program that records the frames, but only when one skeleton/body is in the frame. I looked at the bodyCount method, but it always gives a value of 6 (useless). One thing I tried to do is shown below. This code basically shows the index at which the body being tracked is stored. But, I still can't figure out how to know if there is one or more bodies in the frame.
I would really appreciate any help. 
Thanks in advance.

```
private void Reader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e){
   using (BodyFrame bodyFrame=e.FrameReference.AquireFrame()){
          if (bodyFrame!=null){
                if(this.bodies==null){
                this.bodies=new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount];
                }
          body.Frame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(this.bodies) 

          for(int i=0; i<6;i++){
              if(this.bodies[i].IsTracked){
              Console.WriteLine("Tracked"+i)
               }
           }

      }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the IsTracked property of each body, and store the number of tracked skeleton in a single variable. If this number is equal to 1, there is just one single skeleton tracked, and you can start your recording.

```
    private Body[] bodies = null;

    [...]

    private void Reader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool dataReceived = false;

        using (BodyFrame bodyFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (bodyFrame != null)
            {
                if (this.bodies == null)
                {
                    this.bodies = new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount];
                }

                // The first time GetAndRefreshBodyData is called, Kinect will allocate each Body in the array.
                // As long as those body objects are not disposed and not set to null in the array,
                // those body objects will be re-used.
                bodyFrame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(this.bodies);
                dataReceived = true;
            }
        }

        if (dataReceived)
        {
            int trackedBodyCount = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<this.bodies.Length; ++i)
            {
                if(this.bodies[i].IsTracked) {
                    trackedBodyCount += 1;
                }
            }

            if (trackedBodyCount == 1)
            {
                // One skeleton is tracked
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to do that. Thank so much again!

Comment: I need to get a few more points to be able to upvote. Soon as I do, I will upvote :)